# Removing plus and minus bars from a number picker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi i couldn't fit all my number picker widgets onto the screen. Is there a way to turn off the plus and minus bars on the number picker to save space?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the plus and minus buttons you are simply left with an EditText that only accepts numbers. Why not just use a series of EditTexts?

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

You don't explain how they NumberPickers don't fit, perhaps you could wrap them in a ScrollView or HorizontalScrollView?